# Word for "question that forces someone to answer yes or no"?

Tags: synonyms

I recall reading somewhere a word that was a synonym of "question that forces a yes/no answer", but I don't remember which word was it. Googling gives completely unrelated results.

The word might be restricted to political discussions as a tactic to make the opposite opinion to seem more extreme than it is.

Example:

> A: - I think we spend too much money on NASA.
>
> B: - But if the amount we spend is the minimum needed to make the findings we do, and even a bit less budget would mean **zero** findings, wouldn't you keep it as it is?
>
> A: - You are using a _____, and here we can do other than yes or no.

Comment: *CGEL* calls these 'polar' questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a linguistic point of view, this type of question is known as a [**yes-no-question**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes%E2%80%93no_question), which is a type of [close-ended question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-ended_question).

However, since you mention that this type of question can be used as a tactic, you may also be interested in the informal fallacy known as [**false dilemma**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma), in which someone gives only two options or choices when there is in fact a bigger range of options.